# how do i code for user login when logging in specific form authorized else block them using vb and sql server

Tags: vb.net

My code below does not block other user who's col1 and col2 in sql does not match. Need help resolve

trying to give access to user if userid matches dept name and open specific form. If userid1 and dept1 matches open Form1 and userid2 and dept2 matches open Form2 else unauthorized user.

```
Private Sub BTNLOGIN_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNLOGIN.Click

    Try
        Dim myconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("connection string;")

        myconn.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "select USERNAME,DEPT FROM USERS where USERNAME = '" & TXTBUNAME.Text & "'AND DEPT='" & CmbDept.Text & "'"
        Dim CMD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, myconn)

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader

        If reader.Read Then
            CmbDept.SelectedIndex = "@DEPT"

            Me.Dispose()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized User")


            Me.Show()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



    If CmbDept.Text.Trim = "option1" Then
        Form1.Show()

    End If

    If CmbDept.Text.Trim = "option2" Then
        Form2.Show()
                End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it. You can then see exactly where, how and why it doesn't behave as you expect. If you don't know how to debug, now is the time to learn. It's an essential skill.

Comment: Thanks for your response I got it.

Comment: my code is good for 1 user in each dept. How can  I have multi users from same department but need to authenticate user id with environment login. No passwords stored. SQL table has userid, emp name and dept columns.

Answer (score 0):

my code is good for 1 user in each dept. How can I have multi users from same department but need to authenticate user id with environment login. No password isstored in SQL. Table col's USERID, EMP NAME & DEPT
Try
            Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connection String;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim Command As New SqlCommand("SELECT USERID,Dept FROM TABLENAME WHERE USERNAME ='" & UName & "'and Dept ='" & CmbDept.SelectedItem & "'", conn)

```
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)

        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            If (CmbDept.SelectedIndex = 0) Then

                Dim a As New form1
                a.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf (CmbDept.SelectedIndex = 1) Then
                Dim b As New form2
                b.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("invalid User")
            Me.Show()

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: Need help solving above with multi users login USERID primary key